# Dynamic Array to MS SQL Database

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, global-variables

```
private void getRRvalue(string DELRRNO)
        {
            try {

            DBSFCDataContext SFC = new DBSFCDataContext();
            var query = (from i in SFC.POP10500s where i.POPRCTNM == DELRRNO select new { PONO = i.PONUMBER, DATEREC = i.DATERECD, VENDID = i.VENDORID, ITEMCODE = i.ITEMNMBR, QTYBAGS = i.QTYBAGS, QTYSHIP = i.QTYSHPPD, DEPT = i.TRXLOCTN });
            foreach (var r in query)
            {
               string[] row = { 
                               DELRRNO,
                               r.PONO,
                               Convert.ToDateTime(r.DATEREC).ToString(),
                               r.VENDID,
                               r.ITEMCODE,
                               r.QTYBAGS.ToString(),
                               r.QTYSHIP.ToString(),
                               r.DEPT
                               };

                //glbVariables.getRRNO = ;
                //glbVariables.getPONO = ;
                //glbVariables.getRRdateRec = ;
                //glbVariables.getVendID = ;
                //glbVariables.getItemNO = ;
                //glbVariables.getQtyBags = ;
                //glbVariables.getQtyShipped = ;
                //glbVariables.getLocnCode = ;
            }
            SFC.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
    }
```

I'm new to C#.NET and I was just thinking if I could use a dynamic array like for this code above do I need to declare a global array like this **--> "public static string[] row;"** so I can use this array string in another form by calling it with the data that I have stored from this function, could this happen in c#?

I need help here please anyone that is good at arrays in c#...

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic` here? Should the length of array be `dynamic`?

Comment: Just return the "query" from this method as List or IEnumerable, each row will contain the data you need, and then you can use it in another form.

Comment: Return the Query of this method array the string[] row that i construct in this function be used on another form with the same data query that i have place in this function that is shown above.. can that happen? what function or method should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you desired results, you will have to do little more work. I explain your solution using `List`.

First create a class for your one query result:

```
    public class OneRowData
        {
            public string DELRRNO;
            public string PONO;
            public string DATEREC;
            public string VENDID;
            public string ITEMCODE;
            public string QTYBAGS;
            public string QTYSHIP;
            public string DEPT;
        }
```

In your given code, create a `List` of `OneRowData` type and make it `public static` to access it from outside the class as well:

```
public static List<OneRowData> QueryResults = new List<OneRowData>();
```

Now in your `foreach` loop, create an object of `OneRowData`, assing values to it and add it to the `List`:

```
foreach (var r in query)
            {
               OneRowData Obj = new OneRowData();
               //assing values to them
               Obj.DATEREC = Convert.ToDateTime(r.DATEREC).ToString();
               Obj.DELRRNO = DELRRNO;
               Obj.DEPT = r.DEPT;
               Obj.ITEMCODE = r.ITEMCODE;
               Obj.PONO = r.PONO;
               Obj.QTYBAGS = r.QTYBAGS.ToString();
               Obj.QTYSHIP = r.QTYSHIP.ToString();
               Obj.VENDID = r.VENDID;
               //then add the object to your list
               QueryResults.Add(Obj);
            }
```

Now you can simply call your `List` any where and fetch your data like this:

```
foreach (OneRowData Row in QueryResults)
            {
                //Row.DATEREC
                //Row.DELRRNO
                //call them like this and use as you need
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Shaharyar... This Code Really Helps